# jQuery $.ajax reads from local XML file, doesn't work when creating a localhost website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I was able to read a local XML file using jQuery $.ajax.  It works fine in IE10, but not in IE11 for some reason, but that is another story.

Now, I tried creating a localhost website from the html file I have, and places the xml file in the same folder, but it doesn't read the XML's content.   The is no error as well (no alert popped), so that's interesting.

Can anyone please help with this ?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type:"GET", url:"file.xml", datatype:"xml",

 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.statusText); },

 success: function(xml) {    
 var xmlDoc=$.parseXML(xml);
       ###DO SOME WORK HERE  
 $(xmlDoc).find('item').each( function(){
 var table= $(this).find('something').text(); 
 $("#someelement").append(table);
 })  }  }); 
});
```

As I said, it works perfectly when I open the html file from local folder, but not from the webserver.

Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: Place a breakpoint, e.g. using chromes dev tools, within the success and error functions and inspect the results: what's the returned xml object?

Comment: @AdrianM Try switching the `error` / `success` callback positions to `success` then `error`.

Comment: Switching the success / error didn't help.

Comment: @C.Reed - the 'xml' object is some big Object, how can I read its value ?  The thing is the next line, where I try to parse it, returns null.  So how can I investigate this further ?  Does the xml object have some fields I should be looking at ?

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding this line right after the $.parseXML call:                                                              if(xmlDoc==null && jqXHR != null) xmlDoc=$.parseXML(jqXHR.responseText);

Comment: The `xml` argument to the `success` function is the `XMLDocument`, already parsed, probably. jQuery tries to intelligently pre-parse data returned from an ajax call. If you just do `$(xml)`, skipping the `$.parseXml()` step, it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by adding this line right after the $.parseXML call:

```
if(xmlDoc==null && jqXHR != null) xmlDoc=$.parseXML(jqXHR.responseText);
```

So the XML was actually in the jqXHR.responseText. No idea why though.